# Is it possible to apply condition on Choice column in SharePoint Library?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, choice-field, sharepoint-library, conditional

There is one library having choice column as(Morning/Afternoon/Night).

So requirement is that 
Allow user to choose morning only in morning time frame only. same for other Afternoon/Night.
So how can we can restrict user to select shift(Morning/Afternoon/Night)as per timing frame only.

Comment: Just curious, but if choices are all mutually exclusive, which they are in this case (assuming no overlap of hours), then a user would only have a single choice to select. Why would this be a choice column? Wouldn't it be better served as a calculated column that took time frame into account, and then set the value so that the user wouldn't have to deal with it? Then you can even hide the column from the New and Edit forms so that users cannot change it. Is there any reason why the column would not have a value? This might be a better approach in your case if a value is always needed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to apply a condition on a choice column in SharePoint List/Library.

Though you can achieve this by using some jQuery hacks in the forms where you want to force the user to select a choice value based on time frame.